# Date in where clause returning 0 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2019-express

I am trying to get data as follows
`WHERE DateCommande = '2018-09-05'`
but it doesn't work on my computer.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.Commande;
```

Returns rows, including rows that show `2018-09-05` as the datetime value in a `datetime` column.

However, on SSMS on my computer, if I add a `WHERE` clause, the query returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Commande
  WHERE DateTimeColumn = '2018-09-05 00:00:00.000';
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). We need text output from your SELECT, as well as text sample data and the column definitions for your table. It's not enough just to dump the query and a picture of the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000` is *not* a language- and regional settings-safe format!

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-09-07');
SET LANGUAGE Nederlands;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-09-07');
```

Results ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e9ed7026aa8c07dfa5be496cf0a6676a)):

```
-----------------------
2021-09-07 00:00:00.000

-----------------------
2021-07-09 00:00:00.000
```

Please use `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000` - that T is extremely important. So:

```
WHERE DateCommande = '2018-09-05T00:00:00.000';
```

Or in your case, probably just something closer to what you have in your question, not what you have in your screenshot:

```
WHERE DateCommande = '20180905'; -- YYYYMMDD *not* YYYY-MM-DD
```

But unless you only want those rows without time or are sure there is never going to be a time associated with the date (in which case, why isn't the data type `date`?), neither of those queries will be safe. Better to say:

```
WHERE DateCommande >= '20180905'
  AND DateCommande <  '20180906';
```

See the links in the section entitled `Regional formats` here, for a lot more background:

- [Dating responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Comment: lol @ "Dating responsibly"

Answer (score -2):

**Solve it!** Thank @Aaron Bertrand!

```sql
SET LANGUAGE us_english;
SELECT  *
FROM BdCommerciale2.dbo.Commande
WHERE DateCommande = '2018-09-05';
```

Comment: I don’t think specifying US English language every time you run a date query is worth the convenience of using an unsafe format you happen to like better.

Comment: If you really want to use the format YYYY-MM-DD to specify a datetime variable regardless of language, then you can cast to date then cast to datetime: cast(cast('2021-09-07' As date) As datetime).  Or: Declare @myDate datetime = cast('2021-09-07' As date).  The date data type correctly interprets the value as YYYY-MM-DD regardless of language settings.

Comment: Thank you all, this is mainly my first question here. I will try to be more efficient next time.